# Как можно задать overflow:hidden елементу только с одной стороны?

Tags: css

Чтоб было как на скрине[image: введите сюда описание изображения] ????????

Comment: Не работает....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overflow {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 20%, lightblue 20%)
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="overflow">
    <img src="https://clipart-db.ru/file_content/rastr/retro_car_008.png" alt="" width="300px">
  </div>
</div>
```

вот изображение которое использовал : [машина](https://clipart-db.ru/file_content/rastr/retro_car_008.png)

Comment: Уже решил через clip-path , но все равно спасибо